# igraph compute metrics for each node and its network

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I am curious how to compute some metrics for each node.

For each node compute percentage of fraudulent connections for

- direct node (directed)
- direct node (undirected)
- the friendship network from the node (directed)
- the friendship network from the node (undirected)

  in total and per relationship type.

Getting started with igraph I am not sure how to move forward to writing own graph processing functions (i.e. not only applying degree, pagerank, ...). Looking forward to some suggestions to solve this task with only one pass over the graph.

Minimal sample is here

```
library(igraph)
id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g") 
name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Esther", "Fanny", "Gaby") 
fraud = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE) 
verticeData <- data.frame(id, name, fraud) 
verticeData

src <- c("a", "b", "c", "f", "e", "e", "d", "a")
dst <- c("b", "c", "b", "c", "f", "d", "a", "e")
relationship <-c("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A")
edgeData <- data.frame(src, dst, relationship)
edgeData
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgeData, directed = TRUE, vertices = verticeData)
plot(g, vertex.color=V(g)$fraud)
# TODO compute metrics
```

I do not have privileges to move, so will do manually based on comment from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256859/igraph-compute-metrics-for-each-node-and-its-network

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gapply` function from the `sna` package gives a lot of flexibility to calculate various ego network statistics. It functions more or less like the `apply` family of functions, but specifically loops over network neighborhoods. The `intergraph` package makes it easy to convert between `igraph` and `sna`.

```
library(sna)
net<-intergraph::asNetwork(g)
c <- c(1,2)
funcs <- c(sum,mean)
for (i in funcs){
  for (j in list(1,2,c)){
    print(gapply(net,j,net %v% "fraud",i)) 
  }
}
```

`gapply` in not super straight forward to use. The second argument ("MARGIN") indicates either row-wise (outgoing ties), column-wise (incoming ties), or both (i.e., undirected). The third argument is a vector of statistics to calculate, and the fourth argument is the function you want to use. As you can, there is a lot of flexibility in the third and fourth arguments.

```
> gapply(net,c(1,2),net %v% "fraud",sum)
[1] 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
> gapply(net,c(1),net %v% "fraud",sum)
  Alice     Bob Charlie   David  Esther   Fanny    Gaby 
      0       0       0       1       0       0       0 
> gapply(net,c(2),net %v% "fraud",sum)
  Alice     Bob Charlie   David  Esther   Fanny    Gaby 
      0       1       0       0       1       0       0
```

Comment: I see so I would need 1 pass to get the number of in, one for the outdegree one for the degrees of each node and then 2 more (1x for the "fraud level" per node and 1x for the friend networks fraudulent connections). Isn't that a lot of passes over the graph? is there a possibility to combine these?

Comment: I think it is going to be hard to do this in just one pass. You could loop over the margins and over the function to cut down some steps (I will add this to the answer).

Comment: do you think graph kernels would be maybe better suited to solve this problem?

Comment: My understanding (which is limited) is that graph kernels and isomorphisms are geared toward detecting structural patterns within and between graphs. Not sure if that is helpful for you, since it seems like you are interested in ego network composition. But could be worth looking into.